# How to bind a text input that's inside a dynamic table?

Tags: html, angular, data-binding, html-table, angular-material

I have a table where a column is a text input.
When the user edits the text both a save and cancel button became enabled.
The save button should just send the new value to the server. I can do that one no problem.
But the cancel button I can't figure out how to change the input back. Because with both model or a child element how do I know which element of the table I'm writing in?

The template part:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="gsServersDataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="gsServersHeaders"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: gsServersHeaders;"></tr>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" > {{element.name}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header sortActionDescription="Sort by value"> Value </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <input id="valueInput" type="text" value="{{element.value}}" (keyup)="onChangeValue()">
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="modify">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Modify </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <button id="saveChanges" mat-mini-fab color="primary" (click)="onClickSave()" [disabled]="disabled">
                    <mat-icon>✓</mat-icon>
                </button>

                <button id="cancelChanges" mat-mini-fab color="primary" (click)="onClickCancel(element)" [disabled]="disabled">
                    <mat-icon>X</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
</table>
```

The component part:

```
gsServersDataSource = [{name: 'name1', value: 'value1'}];
gsServersHeaders: string[] = ['name', 'value', 'modify'];

disabled=true;

onChangeValue(){
    this.disabled=false;
}


onClickSave(element: InstanceDataPoint){
    //service call with new value
    this.disabled=true;

}

onClickCancel(element: InstanceDataPoint){
    //Put original back : How to??
    this.disabled=true;
}
```

}

[image: mock]

Answer (score 0):

I created another value for each line that contains the temporary value the user inputted.

When the user wants to save it, it will be posted and on success saved as the original value.

When the user wants to cancel the changes. The temporary value will be reset to the original value.

On the template I'm now using the newValue as the value of the text input.
And I'm passing to the keyup hook the inputted value

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="value">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header sortActionDescription="Sort by value"> Value </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <input id="valueInput" type="text" value="{{element.newValue}}" (keyup)="onChangeValue(element,$event.target.value)">
                </td>
</ng-container>
```

On the component, I'm now saving the inputted value to the newValue on changes to the text input.
On clicking save I'm assigning the newValue to the originalValue if the post is successful.
And on clicking cancel I'm putting the newValue back to the originalValue.

```
onChangeValue(element: InstanceDataPoint, newValue: string){
    element.disabled = false;
    element.newValue = newValue;
}


onClickSave(element: InstanceDataPoint){
    this.gsInstancesService.postModifiedValue(this.selectedEnvironment,
        { "param-name": element.name, "param-val": element.newValue, "server-id": element.server, "language": element.language}).
        subscribe({complete: ()=>element.value=element.newValue});
    element.disabled=true;
}

onClickCancel(element: InstanceDataPoint){
    element.newValue = element.value;
    element.disabled = true;
}
```